# Can you get notes and tasks from Exchange with VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0, exchange-server

I'm currently looking into expanding a project to include the syncing of notes and tasks from a web application with exchange/Outlook.

Though at the moment, this is only an idea.

Unfortunately for me, it's the first time I've considered doing any form of Exchange integration at all from any application.

So I'm wondering, is what I've set out to do even possible?

I'll most likely be using ASP.NET MVC 2, .NET 4 and Exchange 2003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old way to do it would be to use Outlook Interop to automate Outlook to get access to the data. However, this isn't the neatest way of doing things, and you almost certainly wouldn't want to do it on a server.

The new way of doing it is using *Exchange Web Services*, you can find an article [here](http://blogs.visoftinc.com/archive/2008/03/20/Using-Exchange-Web-Services-2007-The-Basics.aspx) about it, but I'm not sure if they're supported on Exchange 2003...